# Backup mysql from files

Tags: mysql, rescue

I have problems running MySQL (I'm in rescue disk and can't run anything) and I would like to backup up the databases from the system files because I'm planning on formatting the system. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your system is not completely dead (i.e. MySQL service can be started):

1) Boot from rescue media

2) Mount your system disk

```
mount /dev/sdX /mnt/tmp
```

3) Mount virtual filesystems

```
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/tmp/dev
mount -t proc proc /mnt/tmp/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/tmp/sys
```

4) Change root

```
chroot /mnt/tmp
```

5) When you're in chroot'ed environment, start MySQL service

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

6) Make db backup as you do it normally

Don't forget to check your backup *before* formatting; you can also backup raw MySQL db files, backups never hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things you can try.
The first *might* work the second **ought to** work but is more complicated.

1. Copy the database files (usually found at `$SOMEPATH/mysql/data`). Make a fresh installation of mysql (use same version and os as the source). Dump the database files in the new installations `data` dir. Start mysql and it might work.
2. Mount the disk on a working computer. Use ["Percona Xtrabackup"](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/) ta take a backup of the data. Then use that backup to restore. (don't ask how to use Xtrabackup, read the docs)

Comment: Make sure the rights are identical. Use `cp -rp` or rsync to be sure.